# How to pass multiple node's address in jest (Elastic Search)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I am new to JEST technology. I am practicing it from `https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest#authentication` link. I am able to create index and adding documents to it, but I want to to pass multiple nodes.

Here is my code

```
JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();

factory.setHttpClientConfig(new HttpClientConfig 
        .Builder("http://192.167.1.2:9200") 
        .defaultCredentials("user", "password")
        .multiThreaded(false) 
        //Per default this implementation will create no more than 2 concurrent connections per given route 
        .defaultMaxTotalConnectionPerRoute(2) // and no more 20 connections in total 
        .maxTotalConnection(5) 
        .build());

JestClient client = factory.getObject();
```

I am having 3 node cluster, so I want to pass 3 nodes in code. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Actually, as written in the [link you gave](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest#authentication), you can pass to the Builder a list, see:

```
JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
factory.setHttpClientConfig(
    new HttpClientConfig.Builder(Arrays.asList("http://192.168.0.88:9200", "http://192.168.0.172:9200"))
        .credentialsProvider(customCredentialsProvider)
        .build()
);
```

Actually to be more precise, the Builder accepts a `Collection<String>`, see: https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/master/jest/src/main/java/io/searchbox/client/config/HttpClientConfig.java#L127

Comment: Hi @asettouf..Thank you for your time. I tried the above code but it seems that it works only if all three nodes are up and running. If one node fails(I did that manually) the code shows error  `Exception in thread "main" io.searchbox.client.config.exception.CouldNotConnectException: Could not connect to http://192.169.1.2:9200`. I want to cover that scenario as well.What could be the possible solution for it.

Comment: @Ash Have you tried using the node discovery? https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest#node-discovery-through-nodes-api

Comment: I tried this,but it is giving same error.    `ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig.Builder(Arrays.asList("http://192.169.1.2:9200","192.169.1.3:9200","192.169.1.4:9200")) 
    .discoveryEnabled(true) 
    .discoveryFrequency(1l, TimeUnit.MINUTES) 
    .discoveryFilter("type:arbitrary") .build();
  System.out.println("connected");`

Comment: Actullay , there is Exception but new index is created with exception, but I can not insert values into that..The code I am trying is 
  `PutMapping putMapping = new PutMapping.Builder( 
    "javatest13", 
    "javatesttype13", 
    "{ \"javatesttype13\" : { \"properties\" : { \"name\" : {\"type\" : \"text\", \"store\" : \"yes\", \"index\" : \"true\" } }}}; "
  ).build(); 
  
  client.execute(putMapping);
     String source="{\"name\":\"kim123\",\"id\":\"12345\",\"address\":\"Newyork3\"}";`

Comment: @Ash From what I've seen so far, either you have a master node you can poll for discovery, or you have to manage the discovery inside your own program.